# How do I use HttpClient PostAsync parameters properly?

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, httpclient, httpwebresponse

So I am working on writing an extension class for my project using HttpClient since I am moving over from HttpWebRequest.

When doing the POST request, how do I send a normal string as a parameter? No json or anything just a simple string.

And this is what it looks like so far.

```
static class HttpClientExtension
    {
        static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        public static string GetHttpResponse(string URL)
        {
            string fail = "Fail";
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(URL);
            HttpResponseMessage Response = client.GetAsync(URL).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            if (Response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                return Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            else
                return fail;
        }

        public static string PostRequest(string URI, string PostParams)
        {
            client.PostAsync(URI, new StringContent(PostParams));
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(URI).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            string content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            return content;
        }
    }
```

If you look at this like

```
client.PostAsync(URI, new StringContent(PostParams));
```

You can see that I just tried creating new StringContent and passing a string into it and the response returned 404 page not found.
How do I properly use Post.Async(); do I send a string or byte array? Because with HttpWebRequest you would do it like this

```
public static void SetPost(this HttpWebRequest request, string postdata)
        {
            request.Method = "POST";
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postdata);

            using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
                requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the `PostRequest` the following is done..

```
client.PostAsync(URI, new StringContent(PostParams));
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(URI).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Which does not capture the response of the POST.

Refactor to

```
public static string PostRequest(string URI, string PostParams) {            
    var response = client.PostAsync(URI, new StringContent(PostParams)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    return content;
}
```

`HttpClient` is primarily meant to be used async so consider refactoring to

```
public static async Task<string> PostRequestAsync(string URI, string PostParams) {            
    var response = await client.PostAsync(URI, new StringContent(PostParams));
    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return content;
}
```

Comment: With the async version how do I grab ahold of the return string?

Comment: @AleksSlade depends on the context in which the request is being made. Apply the rules for how to make async calls. `var result = await HttpClientExtension.PostRequestAsync("URL here", "Params Here")`

Answer (score 4):

You need prepare object and then you will serialize the object using [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/). After that you will prepare byte content from the buffer. We are using api url api/auth/login and it is not full api url as we used dependency injection and configure base address in startup, see the second code.

```
public async void Login(string username, string password)
    {
        LoginDTO login = new LoginDTO();
        login.Email = username;
        login.Password = password;
        var myContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(login);
        var buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myContent);
        var byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(buffer);
        byteContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

        var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("api/auth/login", byteContent);
        var contents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
```

```
services.AddHttpClient<IAuthService, AuthService>(client =>
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44354/");
        });
```

**.NET 5 Solution**

In .NET 5, There is new class JsonContent and you can implement this easily

```
LoginDTO login = new LoginDTO();
login.Email = username;
login.Password = password;

JsonContent content = JsonContent.Create(login);
var url = "http://...";
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, content);
```

Answer (score 2):

I have worked the following (using the package Ngonzalez.ImageProcessorCore).

Query (ASP.NET Core 2 Controller):

```
async Task<byte[]> CreateImage(IFormFile file)
{
  using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
  {
    await file.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
    var image = new Image(memoryStream);
    var height = image.Height < 150 ? image.Height : 150;
    image.Resize((int)(image.Width * height / image.Height), height).Save(memoryStream);
    return memoryStream.ToArray();
  }
}

[HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> ImageAdd(ImageAddVm vm)
{
  byte[] image = null;
  if (vm.File != null && vm.File.Length > 0)
     image = await CreateImage(vm.File);
  if (image != null)
  {
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { vm.ObjectId, image });
    var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var client= new HttpClient();
    await client.PostAsync($"{ApiUrl}/SaveImage", content);
  }
  return RedirectToAction("ReturnAction");
}
```

Api (ASP.NET Core 2 Controller):

```
public class ObjectImage
{
  public int ObjectId { get; set; }
  public byte[] Image { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost("SaveImage")]
public void SaveImage([FromBody]object content)
{
  var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObjectImage>(content.ToString());
  _db.Images.Find(obj.ObjectId).Image = obj.Image;
  _db.SaveChanges();
}
```